# Robotframework - MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException with Firefox

Tags: robotframework

I'v got problem with function move_to_element on Firefox Webdriver (Chrome works well)

```
${SCREEN_WIDTH}   1440
${SCREEN_HEIGHT}  900

Init Firefox
    Create Webdriver  Firefox
    Set Window Size              ${SCREEN_WIDTH}      ${SCREEN_HEIGHT}

Clear Input Text
    [Arguments]  ${locator}
    ${value}=    Get Value     ${locator}
    ${length}=   Get Length    ${value}
    :FOR  ${index}  IN RANGE  ${length}
    \  Press Key  ${locator}  \\8

Clear Bootstrap DatePicker
    [Arguments]  ${locator}
    Scroll Element Into View  ${locator}
    Clear Input Text          ${locator}
    Press Keys                ${locator}    ESC
```

After running this script, on output shows:

```
FAIL    MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: Message: (413.8333435058594, 894.3999938964844) is out of bounds of viewport width (1440) and height (826)
```

My problem is on `Clear Bootstrap DatePicker`. I try solve when I add `Scroll Element Into View  ${locator}` but not work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Scroll Element Into View` do not work in my case. So I implemented `Scroll To Element`

```
Clear Bootstrap DatePicker
    [Arguments]  ${locator}
    Scroll To Element  ${locator}
    Clear Input Text   ${locator}
    Press Keys         ${locator}  ESC

Scroll To Element
    [Arguments]  ${locator}
    ${x}=        Get Horizontal Position  ${locator}
    ${y}=        Get Vertical Position    ${locator}
    Execute Javascript  window.scrollTo(${x}, ${y})
```